# How to find the current location of a file given its old path in git

Tags: git, path, move

After moving a file in git, `git log --follow -- old_path` will give me a history of the file. If I'm lucky, the commit message will tell me where the file has been moved to. For example, `Documentation/kobject.txt` in Linux kernel hhas been moved to `Documentation/core-api/kobject.rst',

```sh
$ git log --follow -- Documentation/kobject.txt
commit 5fed00dcaca8bbd428742a6db1980753290eb204
Author: Sameer Rahmani <lxsameer@gnu.org>
Date:   Tue Feb 25 22:21:25 2020 +0000

    Documentation: kobject.txt has been moved to core-api/kobject.rst

    Moved the `kobject.txt` to `core-api/kobject.rst` and updated the
    `core-api` index to point to it.

    Signed-off-by: Sameer Rahmani <lxsameer@gnu.org>
    [jc: moved it down from the top of core-api/index.rst]
    Link: https://lore.kernel.org/r/20200225222125.61874-2-lxsameer@gnu.org
    Signed-off-by: Jonathan Corbet <corbet@lwn.net>
```

But is there an expedient to find out the current location given an old file path in git?

Comment: The short answer is no. I once tried to figure out how to make `git log --reverse --follow -- old_path` work to do this and it was terribly difficult and I gave up, but ideally, that *ought* to be the way to find it. It just doesn't work.

Comment: You can cobble together some scripts that find the last commit that has it, then look at the next commit after that last commit and see if you can see the file being renamed. That often works, but it's not as good as the way that should work and doesn't. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the tips!